# javascript - eval SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, eval

I'm trying to use JSXGraph to show a function a user inputs in a text field.

This is my code:

```
            var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box', {boundingbox: [-10, 10, 10, -10], axis:true});
        eval("function f(x){ return "+field.value+";}");
        board.create('functiongraph',[function(x){ return f(x); }]);
```

This code works perfectly when the user enters something like: 2*x
But when the user inputs: 2x (without the *), it doesn't work, and I get:
SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal on the eval() line

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `eval` evaluates Javascript, `2x` is not valid Javascript. You need your own parser.

Comment: How could I do that? thanks for your help

Comment: That's not incredibly complicated, but you have to learn some stuff. Start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages

Answer (score 0):

In your example you call `eval()` to create a new JavaScript function which is subsequently plotted. Of course, then you have to supply correct JavaScript.

A first simple enhancement would be to replace all combinations of `digit letter` by `digit*letter`. For example, replace `2x` by `2*x` and `(1+2)x` by `(1+2)*x`. This can be done using the following regular expression.

```
/**
 * Expand math expressions with suppressed multiplication dots.
 * Examples
 *      2x -> 2*x
 *      (2+3)(3+1) -> (2+3)*(3+1)
 * Attention with exponents:
 *      x^2x -> x^2*x
 */
expandShortMath = function(expr) {
    var re = /([\)0-9\.])\s*([\(a-zA-Z_])/g;
    return expr.replace(re, '$1*$2');
};
```

In your example you would use it like this:

```
eval("function f(x){ return " + expandShortMath(field.value) + ";}");
board.create('functiongraph',[function(x){ return f(x); }]);
```

However, for security reasons it is better to avoid calling `eval()`. For this reason, JSXGraph comes with its own parser for the mathematical script language [JessieCode](https://github.com/jsxgraph/JessieCode). This parser can be used by simply supplying `board.create('functiongraph')` with the string containing the function term. But also JessieCode needs the multiplication stars. Again, this can be solved by calling `expandShortMath()`.

```
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box', 
                {boundingbox: [-10, 10, 10, -10], axis:true});
board.create('functiongraph',[expandShortMath(field.value)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression parser of [math.js](http://mathjs.org) may come in handy here. You can do something like:

```
var f = math.eval('f(x) = 2x^3 - 5');
console.log(f(2)); // outputs 11
```